# Why when resizing the user control graph it's not really resized?

Tags: c#

I have a user control chart in my Form1 designer and this is the code to resize it:

```
private void graphChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            graphChart1.Size = new Size(600, 600);
        }
```

When I move the mouse to the control area it's not resizing it make it bigger but deleting some other controls.

This is an image before I move the mouse over the control:

[image]

And this is an image when I moved the mouse over the control:

[image]

This is the code of the user control where the chart is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace GatherLinks
{

    public partial class GraphChart : UserControl
    {
        public GraphChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private double f(int i)
        {
            var f1 = 59894 - (8128 * i) + (262 * i * i) - (1.6 * i * i * i);
            return f1;
        }

        private void GraphChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
            {
                Name = "Series1",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };

            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                series1.Points.AddXY(i, f(i));
            }
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I did this in the user control class code:

```
public void ChangeChartSize(int width, int height)
{
            chart1.Size = new Size(width, height);
            chart1.Invalidate();
}
```

I had to add `chart1.Invalidate();` to make it to take effect but then it sized the chart it self inside the user control. The user control was not changed.

So in the Form1 mouse enter I also changing the graphChart1 the control size:

```
private void graphChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            graphChart1.ChangeChartSize(600, 600);
            graphChart1.Size = new Size(600, 600);
}
```

The problem is that now it's taking a lot of time almost 20 seconds or so until it take effect when I'm moving the mouse over the control. If I will remove the second line:

```
graphChart1.Size = new Size(600, 600);
```

it will work fast but then it will change the chart only inside the control but it won't change the control size.

Tried also with invalidate:

```
private void graphChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            graphChart1.ChangeChartSize(600, 600);
            graphChart1.Size = new Size(600, 600);
            graphChart1.Invalidate();
}
```

But still very slow. Maybe I need to change the control it self size also in the user control class code and not in Form1 ?

Comment: In general I wanted to make that when I move with the mouse over the control this chart user control it will be resize and also will change it's location to the center of screen then when I move the mouse out of the user control chart area it will get back to it's original location and size.

Comment: Maybe I need also to resize the user control it self ? And not only the chart ?

Comment: Nikola I tried to make graphChart1.Invalidate(); just after the graphChart1.Size line but it didn't help just made it slower until the event change but same problem as above.

Comment: Check the answer now. The first answer was published before you posted the code so I deleted it. Now its better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are resizing the GraphicChart (your user control) but not the Chart itself. You could add the method in your GraphChart class in order to do that. This is the method that will change the chart size:

```
public void ChangeChartSize(int width, int height)
{
     chart1.Size = new Size(width, height);
}
```

And in your mouse enter event handler you could call something like this:

```
void graphicChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     graphChart1.ChangeChartSize(600, 600);
}
```

Comment: Ok im updating my question now editing it with what I did now it's not working good yet working but not good.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the questions, I was working on something else. I'm glad I could help. See ya!

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic, What reference should I add to use ChangeChartSize?

Comment: @VR17 You don't have do add the reference but to implement the method that changes the size of the graph.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic, What is graphChart1 here? chart1 is the name of my chart

Comment: @VR17 As you can see in question, graphChart1 is an instance of the GraphChart class derived from the UserControl which has chart1 instance of the Chart control

Answer (score 0):

With `graphChart1.Size =` you are resizing your container but not the chart within it.

The easiest work-around is probably to make `chart1` public in the control and do `graphChart1.chart1.Size =` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the user control class code I did:

```
public void ChangeChartSize(int width, int height)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(width, height);
            chart1.Size = new Size(width, height);
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }
```

In Form1 I did:

```
private void graphChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            graphChart1.ChangeChartSize(600, 600);
        }
```

Working smooth.